# Does weaviate support bulk deletes?

Tags: weaviate

I am looking at using weaviate for vector searching, but would also like to have an age off feature for rolling off old records.  Does weaviate have any type of bulk delete operation to accomplish this?  I would imagine that single deletes by ids would have an effect on the performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't have a way to [batch](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/restful-api-references/batch.html) delete *but* you can remove a class.

So, if you have a class called `Foobar` that has e.g., 1M data objects. You can simply do a `DELETE v1/schema/Foobar`.

In case there is another use case where this might add value you can add it [here](https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues) too.